# CSS doesn't effect dynamically created list on Phonegap

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, dynamic-list

similar to my question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962593/my-list-wont-take-the-css-in-phonegap)
and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786465/jquery-mobile-dynamic-listview-loses-style-data-inset-after-updating)

however, still haven't sorted any solution..
i have in the `<body>` an unordered list `<ul>` each element of which is added after performing a query to a database..So according to the result, i have the corresponding `<li>` tags created..

Ther problem is, that although i have some css to seperate `<li>` to "odd" and "even" so that i can apply some different styles, and i have confirmed, that the "odd" and even" attibute has passed as an attribute (classname) to `<li>` still the corresponding css rules, do not apply

here is some of my code.. first the html part

```
<div id="sqldiv">
   <ul class="test" id="attempt">
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the javascript part..

```
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var somevariable =  results.rows.item(i).dbvariable;
                if (i%2==0)
                lt='Even';
                else
                lt='Odd';
                var newLI = document.createElement("LI"); 
                newLI.className = lt;
                var htmlcontainer = ("<div>my text :" + my variables + "</div><div>my text :</div><div>" my variables + "</div>");
                newLI.innerHTML = htmlcontainer ;
                var gl = document.getElementById("attempt"); 
                gl.appendChild(newLI);
            }
```

and the css

```
li {
background: #8258FA;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-image:none;
margin: 5px 5px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
li.odd  {
border-bottom :1px dotted #ccc;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-image:none;
margin: 5px 5px;
background: #000000;
}
```

the li styling does apply, but the styling by class (li.odd) doesn't

Comment: Could you give an example of your code, i.e. what the list looks like and how you update it?

Comment: It's a lot more efficient to use nth-child selectors to do your zebra striping:  `li:nth-child(even) { background: #CCC }`

Comment: i have edited my initial post guys..with some code..

Comment: I would recommend to use jQuery to add classnames etc. There you have no browser specific problems etc.

Comment: can you be more specific mate..?? what would you change..??? i ve confirmed, that the class name does apply to each list element..it is just that css doesn't apply to it..perhaps due to some difference while loading..!??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spending last 24 hours searching..i tried sth that didn't cross my mind..!!!!

in javascript i name class Even and Odd..and on css i have .even and .odd rules.. and this worked great on another project..!!!

but, for some reason,  in this case there seemed to be a "case sensitive" issue.. since i changed css rule to .Even and .Odd, they were applied successfully..

before reaching this, i had also tried assigning dynamic css rules using jquery..and after some attempts, i ended up to the case sensitive..